# Constructing a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have data in this format;

```
my_dict = {
    'data1':[
        {'age':32,'height':43,'weight':67},
        {'age':21,'height':33,'weight':34}
    ],
    'data2':[
        {'name':'james','department':'web'},
        {'name':'Joe','department':'social'}
    ]
}
```

I want to get age, weight, and name. How can I construct a list of dictionaries of all records?
e.g)

```
data = [{'age':32, 'weight':43, 'name':'james'},
        {'age':32, 'weight':33, 'name':'joe'}    ]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you post your attempt as well?

Comment: Shouldn't joes age be 21?

Comment: the real code and data is huge and a bit messy, I can tell you what I tried. I tried to create a dictionary and list and I looped through the data by constructing a dictionary and appending it into the final list, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: please don't look at data, its just random, what I need is final list with those keys.

Comment: how this data is corelated?

Comment: How can we help you if we can't see what the input is? We see what output you want but without an example of input it is very difficult to guide you. It's like asking someone to build you a house but you dont tell them what you want or give them blueprints

Comment: i have posted the input as well, as my_dict at top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. One easy to understand method is to do a for loop with a zip iterator:

```
data = []

for data1, data2 in zip(my_dict.get('data1'), my_dict.get('data2')):
    data.append({'age':data1.get('age'),
                 'weight':data1.get('weight'),
                 'name':data2.get('name')})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do what you want. We make `data` a list of empty `dict`s and then based on the index of a `dict` within one of the data lists, we update the corresponding `dict` in the `data` list.

```
# list of empty dicts
data = [{} for i in range(2)]
# holds what info we want
select = {'age', 'weight', 'name'}
for k in my_dict:
    for idx, i in enumerate(my_dict[k]):
        data[idx].update({k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in select})

print(data)
```

Output

```
[{'age': 32, 'name': 'james', 'weight': 67},
 {'age': 21, 'name': 'Joe', 'weight': 34}]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I couldn't use this method as my data file is huge and I can't manage to delete unnecessary keys.

Comment: @mahrukhwahab No worries! Fair point. I have updated my answer.